# I want to know how to return the price and description from my 1rst Class into my 2nd Class?

Tags: java

I'm sorry for being so inexperienced, I'm only 15 and I just started trying to learn Java a day ago. This is a test program.

1rst Class:

```
public class CoffeeProgram {
public static void main(String[] args) {



      CoffeeReturn.CoffeeDesc(1101101);
      System.out.print("Price of Coffee: $");
      System.out.println(CoffeeReturn.CoffeeCode(1101101)); 
     }

    }
    class CoffeeReturn{

      static double CoffeeCode(double code){

       double price = 0.0;

       if(code == 1101101){

        price = 1.99;
                }
        return price; 
        }
      public static void CoffeeDesc(double code){
       String desc = "Black Coffee w/ Sugar";
       if(code == 1101101){
       System.out.println("Description: "+desc);
       }}}
```

2nd Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class GUI extends JFrame {
public static void main (String args[]) {
GUI window = new GUI();
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setSize(200, 200);
window.setVisible(true);
window.setTitle("Coffee Program");}
JLabel CoffeeProgram;
JButton button;
JTextField textfield;

public GUI() {
 setLayout(new FlowLayout());

 CoffeeProgram = new JLabel("Enter Code Here:");
 add(CoffeeProgram);

 textfield = new JTextField(15);
 add(textfield);

 button = new JButton("Submit Code");
 add(button);
```

I want to make the program understand the code I put in, and afterwards show me the price and description. It's a lot to ask for, sorry, but I really want to learn. I had trouble trying to make the 2nd Class recieve String desc and also the price :(
In advance, thanks for the help, I appreciate it !
This is the program GUI so far: http://gyazo.com/daef469d089c8a09d9142038f031770c

Comment: Hard to follow your code and understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll try and make it more clear.

Comment: I know the question is pretty messed up, but come on, it's just a 15 year old kid trying to learn java !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has got two main methods, so essentially (in basic terms), they are ***not connected***

The things that you are looking for is an reference to the swing components. For example, modifying your program would look like following:

GUI.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    JLabel CoffeeProgram;
    JButton button;
    JTextField textfield;
    JLabel outputPrice;
    JLabel outputDesc;

    public GUI() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        CoffeeProgram = new JLabel("Enter Code Here:");
        add(CoffeeProgram);
        textfield = new JTextField(15);
        add(textfield);
        outputPrice = new JLabel("Output price here");
        add(outputPrice);
        outputDesc = new JLabel("Desc: ");
        add(outputDesc);    
        button = new JButton("Submit Code");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            CoffeeReturn returnOutputPrice = new CoffeeReturn();
            double returnPrice = returnOutputPrice.CoffeeCode(1101101);
            outputPrice.setText(String.valueOf(returnPrice));

            String returnDescription = returnOutputPrice.CoffeeDesc(1101101);
            outputDesc.setText(returnDescription);
        }});

    }
}
```

coffeeprogram.java:

import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class coffeeprogram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // GUI stuff
        GUI window = new GUI();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(200, 200);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("Coffee Program");


        CoffeeReturn returnPrice = new CoffeeReturn();

        String returnDesc = returnPrice.CoffeeDesc(1101101);
        window.outputDesc.setText(returnDesc);
    }
}

class CoffeeReturn {

        public double CoffeeCode(double code) {
            double price = 0.0;
            if (code == 1101101) {
                price = 1.99;
            }
            return price;
        }

        public String CoffeeDesc(double code) {
            String desc = "Black Coffee w/ Sugar";
            if (code == 1101101) {
                return desc;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Invalid code";
            }
        }
    }
```

I just removed the main method in GUI.java and added an event listener to the button, i.e, when you click the button, we need to define what it needs to do (called as `ActionEvent`). Then you just use the `setText(String)` methods defined for each JLabel component and set the values to your output.

Simple ActionEvent example:

Reference: [1] http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/278-how-add-actionlistener-jbutton-swing.html

[2] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ -> Has a list of things you could go through

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good effort for your 1st day.

For interaction you want to use an ActionListener. Oracle has [some good documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) on their site.

Also you should consider following a [style guide](http://www.javaranch.com/styleLong.jsp), it will make your code easier to read in the long run.